# Viewing totals (Format below)

Tags: mysql

With the code shown below:

```
SELECT c.idBase, t.Estado FROM argentina.Tickets_2018 t
LEFT JOIN argentina.ContenidoBases c 
ON t.ANI = c.ANI 
WHERE t.idCampania = 8 AND t.Fecha BETWEEN "2018-04-04" AND "2018-04-15"
```

The columns and data retrieved is like this:

```
Base  |   Estado   
----------------
139   |  ANSWER
139   |  ANSWER
139   |  NOANSWER
139   |  NOANSWER
139   |  ANSWER
```

What I want is to view info like this (totals):

```
Base  |   Estado   |   Total
----------------
139   |  ANSWER    |     3
139   |  NOANSWER  |     2
```

What I'm doing wrong in my code? (I have a lot of "Base"s (like 139, 45, 2, etc))

Comment: Bad English. Sorry :(

Comment: Did you try group by?

Comment: Yep, but nothing.

Comment: You need to group by the 2 columns you have in your output and count the number of rows in each group. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks <3 @forpas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.idBase, t.Estado, count(*) as total FROM argentina.Tickets_2018 t
LEFT JOIN argentina.ContenidoBases c 
ON t.ANI = c.ANI 
WHERE t.idCampania = 8 AND t.Fecha BETWEEN "2018-04-04" AND "2018-04-15"
Group by c.idBase, t.Estado
```

The group by will allow you to do a count which will give you the total :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`, this result is possible:

```
SELECT c.idBase, t.Estado, COUNT(c.idBase) AS `Total`
FROM argentina.Tickets_2018 t
LEFT JOIN argentina.ContenidoBases c ON t.ANI = c.ANI 
WHERE t.idCampania = 8 AND t.Fecha BETWEEN "2018-04-04" AND "2018-04-15"
GROUP BY c.idBase, t.Estado
```

As seeing in your expected output, `Base` is the alias name for the `id` column. If so use `SELECT id AS Base,` and `GROUP BY c.id`. If not, your actual column name is `idBase` use the query above.